# Why is my SqlCommand returning a string when it should be an int?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I have a query that should *always* be returning a single int. I have now logged it returning a string entirely unrelated to what it should be.

We've been getting some random FormatExceptions that we've tracked down to several database queries. After some additional logging, I found that, this morning, the query below returned the string "gladiator". Website.PkID is an int column and works most of the time, but some times it fails miserably and returns either an int that's waaaay out there (bigger than any valid WebsiteID) or a random string.

This particular query is hit once per session start. It's not using a shared connection, so I'm having trouble understanding how it could get such a mixed-up result. Could there be some kind of corruption in the connection pools?

I don't think the problem is isolated to this query. I've seen similar FormatExceptions (because of an unexpected result) coming from LINQ queries as well. We've also spotted some of these errors around the same times:

> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Could it be a connection issue? Or maybe we're getting result sets mixed up between the db server and the web server? This has really got me scratching my head.

Offending query:

```
public static int GetActiveWebSiteID(string storeID, string statusID)
{
    int retval;

    string sql = @"SELECT isnull(MAX(PkID),0) FROM WebSite 
                   WHERE StoreID = @StoreID 
                   AND WebSiteStatusID = @WebSiteStatusID";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StoreID", (object)storeID ?? DBNull.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WebSiteStatusID", (object)statusID ?? DBNull.Value);

    conn.Open();
    using(conn)
    {
        var scalar = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // <-- This value returned here should only ever be an int, but randomly is a string

        retval = Convert.ToInt32(scalar);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

The above query has worked fine for years until recently. We now have a bunch of additional LINQ queries in the app (not sure if that makes a difference). We're running .Net 3.5.

Comment: What is the value of 'scalar' when it is a string?

Comment: may be it is string when it is "0" MAX(PkID) is null

Comment: As mentioned, the string I saw logged in error was "gladiator". I have a hunch this is somehow mixed-up with other query results from somewhere in the system, specifically a keyword search. But I can't prove that yet.

Comment: I've never seen result sets get screwed up. Could the logging have a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a few months of ignoring this issue, it started to reach a critical mass as traffic gradually increased. We increased logging and found numerous definitive instances where, under heavy load, completely different result sets would get returned to unrelated queries.

We watched the queries in Profiler and were able to see that the bad results were always associated with the same spid, and that each bad result was always one query behind the actual sql statement being queried. It was like a result set got missed and whatever result set was next in the spid (from another connection in the same pool) was returned. Crazy.

Through trial and error, we eventually tracked down a handful of SqlCommand or LINQ queries whose SqlConnection wasn't closed immediately after use. Instead, through some sloppy programming originating from a misunderstanding of LINQ connections, the DataContext objects were disposed (and connections closed) only at the end of a request rather than immediately.

Once we refactored these methods to immediately close the connection with a C# "using" block (freeing up that pool for the next request), we received no more errors. While we still don't know the underlying reason that a connection pool would get so mixed up, we were able to cease all errors of this type. This problem was resolved in conjunction with another similar error I posted, found here: [What Causes "Internal Connection Fatal Errors"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155263/what-causes-internal-connection-fatal-errors)

Comment: I wonder whether you have ever after found and underlying reason for the mentioned problem? I am experiencing similar issues (such as empty string being returned when asking for a Configuration table entry that was there for years or connection dropouts as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155263/what-causes-internal-connection-fatal-errors). Closing the connection "faster" sounds like a workaround. Data should never be mixed between different SqlConnection instances, should it? I would be grateful if you could elaborate on that. :)

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - This was 13 years ago and we never discovered the root cause. My suspicion is that there was some bug in the underlying connection pool driver which buckled under pressure and did the unthinkable: handing some other query's results back to a different caller. I would hope that modern drivers have solved this, but I haven't personally seen it in over a decade!

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - Microsoft just disclosed a vulnerability in modern SqlClient implementations (https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8g2p-5pqh-5jmc) that could be a likely root cause of your observations, and updating to the latest library version should fix it: "A vulnerability exists in System.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient libraries where a timeout occurring under high load can cause incorrect data to be returned as the result of an asynchronously executed query."

Answer (score 1):

I think that you were thinking about `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` that returns the number of rows affected within an int value...

This is the definition of the ExecuteScalar method:

```
public override object ExecuteScalar()
Member of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
```

**Summary:**

Executes the query, and **returns the first column of the first row** in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

**Returns:**

The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty.

So, I think that the common way of returning that column is as a string representation of the column value.

Comment: ExecuteScalar() is exactly what I want. I don't care about the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently seen a case where code was switching connection strings unexpectedly. For diagnostic purposes, please hard code the connection string and see if the problem goes away.

Also, for sanity's sake, please use nested using blocks like:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("hard-coded connection string"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        // more init
        object scalar = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        // process result
    }
 }
```

It wouldn't surprise me to find there are two database instances, and in one, PkID is an int, in another it's varchar.

---

Take a look with SQL Profiler to see if you can catch the return of "gladiator". In the other case I was working with, SQL Profiler showed nothing at all, indicating that the actual query was going to a different database.

Comment: There's only one valid database with a Website table out there. Good idea on cleaning up the usings a little bit - that much couldn't hurt anything.

Comment: I presume you know this because you used the Profiler and saw the call that returned "gladiator"?

Answer (score 0):

The ExecuteScalar() function's return type is `object`, and you declare your result variable with the `var` keyword.  That's not really a good combination, because you're putting a lot of pressure on the system to get the type inference right.

Comment: The column is an int and the result was a string of "gladiator". I don't see how type inference has anything to do with this. An int column, or any aggregation thereof, should never return a string.

Comment: Type inference should never spawn a "gladiator" :)

Comment: Nor should the code he posted, unless PkID isn't really an int column.

Comment: The compiler either resolves the type exactly or gives an ambiguity error.

Comment: But how do you know in this case that it resolved to the type you expect?  Convert.ToInt32() will accept almost anything, and that's the only other place it's used.

Answer (score 0):

the Field "PkID" is a varchar/char in the "WebSite" Table.

If the "ISNULL" part of the query is true then it will return an integer (0), else it will return an string with the value of "PkID"

Comment: As mentioned in the question, Website.PkID is an int column.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one WebSite table. Can you qualify the table with schema name:

SELECT isnull(MAX(PkID),0) FROM YourSchema.WebSite 
                   WHERE StoreID = @StoreID 
                   AND WebSiteStatusID = @WebSiteStatusID

Comment: There is only one Website table.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any commonality to when it fails to return an int?

Since your query only ever returns a single column in a single row, what do you get if you use a more typesafe ExecuteReader and take the first column's value?

Is it always returning a row?  If the `WHERE` clause causes it to return no rows (say your parameters are not what you think they are), your `ISNULL` doesn't come into effect - there are no rows at all, and ExecuteScalar is supposed to return a NULL.

Comment: I stripped out some of the code for the sake of brevity in the above example. The real code has more logging and also checks the value of "scalar" for null and DbNull before trying to convert to an int. These checks handle the no-result case.

Comment: But as you recommend, I'll try reworking the query to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think neither your posted query nor LINQ are the problem.

Are you really sure you're looking at the right source? How is the method called? How is logging done?

[Select isn't broken.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001079.html)

Comment: Yes, it's the right source. I've removed the log4net logging in the example code above for brevity, and had injected very specific logging that told me the inputs and output.

I have a hunch that there might be some kind of network thing going on between the sql server and web server. We've had weird issues before, though never of this severity.

Comment: You are not convincing me. When you've used the SQL Profiler and seen the code actually run on the server you expect it to run on, then we'll know what server it's running on. Until then, you're guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that Settings.ConnString is read from Web.Config or the registry and is re-used other static routines.  Could it be possible that there is a timing issue where a second method is executed prior to the call to cmd.ExecuteScalar() in your routine which modifies cmd.CommandText on the connection?

Hope this helps,

Bill