# What Causes "Internal connection fatal errors"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-6, sql-server-2000, asp.net-3.5

I've got a number of ASP.Net websites (.Net v3.5) running on a server with a SQL 2000 database backend. For several months, I've been receiving seemingly random InvalidOperationExceptions with the message "Internal connection fatal error". Sometimes there's a few days in between, while other times there are multiple errors per day.

The exception is not limited to one site in particular, though they share business and data access assemblies. The error seems to always be thrown from SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(). It sometimes is thrown from old-school direct SqlCommand.Execute() calls, while other times it is thrown from Linq2Sql code.

I've been assured by the network guys that there are no errors or packets lost on their end. Has anyone else experienced this? Could it be a driver problem? We have been unable as of yet to pinpoint a specific trigger for this exception.

We're running II6 on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a few months of ignoring this issue, it started to reach a critical mass as traffic gradually increased. Under heavy load, including some crawlers, things got crazy and these errors poured in nonstop.

Through trial and error, we eventually tracked down a handful of SqlCommand or LINQ queries whose SqlConnection wasn't closed immediately after use. Instead, through some sloppy programming originating from a misunderstanding of LINQ connections, the DataContext objects were disposed (and connections closed) only at the end of a request rather than immediately.

Once we refactored these methods to immediately close the connection with a C# "using" block (freeing up that pool for the next request), we received no more errors. While we still don't know the underlying reason that a connection pool would get so mixed up, we were able to cease all errors of this type. This problem was resolved in conjunction with another similar error I posted, found here: [Why is my SqlCommand returning a string when it should be an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882784/why-is-my-sqlcommand-returning-a-string-when-it-should-be-an-int)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the database connection is getting dropped or timing out.

We recently had similar issues moving to IIS 6 from IIS 5 connecting to SQL 2000. Our issue was solved by increasing number of ephemeral ports available.

Look at the usage of the ephemeral ports by the IIS server. The default max no. of ports available is normally 4000. You might want to consider increasing this if the sites on your server are particularly busy or your application is making a lot of database calls.

You can monitor these first to see if going over max limit.

Search Microsoft Knowledge base for "MaxUserPort" and "TcpTimedWaitDelay" and make necessary registry changes. Make sure you back up registry or snapshot server before making the changes. Will need to reboot for changes to take effect.

You should double check your database and recordset connection are being closed after use. Not closing will use up this port range unnecessarily.

Check the efficiency of your stored procedures anyway as they might be taking longer than they need too.

"If you rapidly open and close 4000 sockets in less than four minutes, you will reach the default maximum setting for client anonymous ports, and new socket connection attempts fail until the existing set of TIME_WAIT sockets times out." - from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328476

Answer (score 1):

Check your server's LOG folder (\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG or similar) for files named SqlDump*.mdmp and SqlDump*.txt. If you do find any you'll have to take it to Product Support.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a new EF Core project and was trying to create the database to an external Linux server instead of a Windows Server or local one. After hours of searching I found out that I am using MySQL instead of the Microsoft SQL server.

I found it weird that everyone was using 1433 instead of the usual 3306. So to fix my 'Internal connection fatal error' I had to set up a docker instance of SQL Server bound to its default port of 1433.

It literally was that simple. In the docker repo look for "microsoft-mssql-server" and run the image as described neatly in the description below. Everything works now and I am able to push my database from my EF Core project to an external server.