# Internal connection fatal error with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection

I have web application with MVC and in my local and other servers it's working proper but today, I am getting  'Internal connection fatal error...' in the code below.

I checked StackOverflow and I think this problem is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155263/what-causes-internal-connection-fatal-errors) . Because in that question user solve problem with using block. In my problem I already use 'using' block.

```
        using (DEMOEntities context = new DEMOEntities())
        {
            var retVal = context.Mg_Definitions();
            ViewBag.List = retVal.ToList();// error occurs here
        }
```

I'm using Entity Framework and I can get easily return value a stored procedure but when I attempt ToList I see an error?

Should I post the stack trace an error to get help?

Thanks

Comment: Hello saulyasar, can you show your Mg_Definitions model, and the data you are trying to retrieve ?

Comment: your answer should be in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155263/what-causes-internal-connection-fatal-errors)

Comment: hi @jamiedanq i read that solution but i'm also use 'using' block in my code.I'm getting error on ToList() step.

Comment: hi @Munzer i try to retrieve one list from sql(i tried procedure its working also on debugging it returns value) and i get error in ToList() step

Comment: I had almost similar issue when I run .NET Core App in Linux server, and resolved by doing following steps, 
1. Installed ICU Libs in the Linux server
    (`yum install libicu`)
2. Set the Globalization Invariant mode to false. Added following in .csproj file,
    `<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="Sytem.Globalization.Invarinat" Value="false" />`