# MS SQL Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15 on setting Dependency

Tags: c#, sql-server

> THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE
>
> Because I am having error only after porting (direct copy of code)
>   from one server to another. So, I know this code has been working for
>   a long time. The only variables are VS2015 and SQL Server Enterprise.

I have an app that works perfectly on a Server running VS2010 and SqlExpress

I have ported to a server running VS2015 and Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit)

On the new machine I keep getting this issue on the ExecuteReader line:

What does this error mean?

```
string sqlCommandText; 
        if (Master.G.AgentHandlesAllExchanges)
        {
            sqlCommandText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [" + AccountCode + "].[Orders] WHERE [Status] = 'NEW'";
        }
        else{
            sqlCommandText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [" + AccountCode + "].[Orders] WHERE [Exchange] = 'Equity' AND [Status] = 'NEW'";
        }

    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Open();
    }

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, conn))
    {

        Dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

        Dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
```

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079   Message=Internal connection fatal error. Error
>   state: 15, Token : 1   Source=System.Data   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>          at Cobra.SqlPA.InitialiseDependencyWORK(Action onDependencyMethod) in C:\Projects\CobraPROD\CobraPROD\SqlPA.cs:line
>   251
>          at Cobra.SqlPA.InitialiseDependency(Action onDependencyMethod) in C:\Projects\CobraPROD\CobraPROD\SqlPA.cs:line 222
>          at Cobra.modelAgent1.calcSignal(SingleProductData MPD) in C:\Projects\CobraPROD\CobraPROD\Models.cs:line 2029
>          at Cobra.modelAgent1.NewOrdersCallBack() in C:\Projects\CobraPROD\CobraPROD\Models.cs:line 1857
>          at Cobra.SqlPA.OnDependencyChange(Object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Projects\CobraPROD\CobraPROD\SqlPA.cs:line 287
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.EventContextPair.Invoke(SqlNotificationEventArgs
>   args)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Invalidate(SqlNotificationType
>   type, SqlNotificationInfo info, SqlNotificationSource source)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependencyPerAppDomainDispatcher.InvalidateCommandID(SqlNotification
>   sqlNotification)   InnerException:

Comment: Good. I wouldn't want to see this query run, eg if someone entered `SomeTable] where 1=0; Drop Table Users;--` as the AccountCode variable

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: He is talking about sql injection and unfortunately he is right! This is not a secure query. To respond your question, are you sure that your account name exists in your new sql server instance ?

Comment: Yes definitely. There is only 1 AccountCode at the moment, and this problem is intermittant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Causes "Internal connection fatal errors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155263/what-causes-internal-connection-fatal-errors)

Comment: See edit. This is not a duplicate

Comment: What's the `@@VERSION` of both SQL Servers? If your server isn't patched to the [latest available build](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/), try that (or, if you can't, at least test against the developer edition of the same version to see if SQL Server is the problem). Patching .NET is another option, although that's a less likely source of trouble. Also, are you using the exact same database (as in backup-restore) on both servers, or is there variation in that? Your use of `AccountCode` as a custom schema (as opposed to the more common `dbo`) could trigger edge cases in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a dotnet error.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs

```
    // For portability only
    public virtual bool AllowReadStreamBuffering {
        get {
            return false;
        }
        set {
            if (value) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.NotSupported));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is an mssql problem. What is this code? What do you mean?