# Strange behavior in SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, asp.net-2.0

I am currently trying to stabilize an asp.net 2.0 website.
I am about 95% sure that the main problem in the stability of the system is that the C# code is leaking SQL connections.

The accepted answer on this post describes exactly my problem:

[Why is my SqlCommand returning a string when it should be an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882784/why-is-my-sqlcommand-returning-a-string-when-it-should-be-an-int)

That beign said, I am currently running this sql statement to pinpoint the possible problem:

```
SELECT S.spid, login_time, last_batch, status, hostname, program_name, cmd,
(
  select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(S.sql_handle)
) as last_sql
FROM sys.sysprocesses S
where dbid > 0
and DB_NAME(dbid) = 'db'
and loginame = 'login'
order by last_batch asc
```

What I find weird is that the login used to connect to the DB from the website keeps returning last_sql as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE name
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
...
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
... Procedure code
```

The question is, why would a create procedure statement be run over and over?

Also, is it a bad practice to have 3-4 (not so active) website connecting to DB using the same connection string?

Comment: dm_exec_sql_text always shows the procedure that is being executed as "create procedure..."

Comment: If you think it's leaking SQL connections, have you looked at the c# side to ensure that all SqlConnections are part of a `using` block?

Comment: Sadly, the whole website is using sloppy programmation and isn't using this practice but everything I investiguated is opened / closed using DataAdapters.